# Get checked checkboxes from most recent .change() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, onchange

I am having trouble with a fundamental question, but can't even figure out what the proper terms to research to help myself are.

In essence, I have a `.change()` listener that listens for changes in checkboxes within a `div` (they toggle Leaflet Map layers). I want to create a variable that keeps a listing of the checked checkboxes. I can do this, however, it appears to keep individual instances of which layers were checked, for each of the times the `.change()` listener fires. Some code that should recreate the issue:

```
var lyrs;

$("div#myID input:checkbox").change(function() {
    lyrs = $("div#myID input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() { return this.id });
    console.log('in .change(): ', lyrs)
    legendFunction( lyrs );

});

function legendFunction( lyrs ) {
    map.on('click', function() {
        console.log('in legendFunction: ', lyrs);
    });
};
```

When I print the variable to the console in the `.change` callback function, a single `lyrs` object exists. However, when I print it from the `.on('click')` callback function in the `legendFunction`, it prints a list (for lack of better word) of layers that were checked during each time a checkbox was checked or unchecked. The image below shows this:

[image]

What is going on? How do I get the `lyrs` variable in the `.on('click')` function to correspond to only the layers for the most recent `.change()` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are binding a listener to the `map`'s click event every time you call the `legendFunction`. This is because every time that function is called, you pass the `lyrs` array as a parameter (which is different that your `lyrs` variable defined at the top of your script) and then you do the binding, so you're creating a closure that remembers the value of this array for that time and for every subsequent time you call the function.

Your program is basically doing this:

**You check the checkbox with the id `landfireEVT`**

- In the change callback you'll have `lyrs = ['landfireEVT']`
- When you call the `legendFunction` you add a new binding to the `map` element and it will "remember" `lyrs = [landfireEVT]`
- If you click on the `map` element, the event that was just bound will fire and in the console you'll see the value of `lyrs = ['landfireEVT']`

**Now somebody checks the checkbox with the id `agc`**

- In the change callback you'll have `lyrs = ['landfireEVT','agc']`
- When you call the `legendFunction` you add a new binding to the `map` element and it will "remember" `lyrs = ['landfireEVT','agc']`

  - If you click on the `map` element, the first callback that was previously bound to the click event will fire and you'll see in the console `lyrs = ['landfireEVT']`, and after that the second callback that was just bound to the click event will fire and you'll see the value of `lyrs = ['landfireEVT','agc']`

I would binding the event just once and keeping the updated checkbox list in the lyrs variable

```
var lyrs;
map.on('click', function() {
   //lyrs will always be the variable defined above anytime somebody clicks on the map element.
   console.log('in legendFunction: ', lyrs);
 });

$("div#myID input:checkbox").change(function() {
  lyrs = $("div#myID input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() { return this.id });
  //add here any other logic you need to notify somebody else that a checkbox changed.
});
```

You can read more about closures and scope here https://community.risingstack.com/explaining-javascript-closure-scope-chain-examples/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a [Leaflet Event](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-event) callback is being registered each time a the checkbox is clicked, via `legendFunction`. So, each time you click on the map, Leaflet is executing the callback with the value for `lyrs` that was used to register the callback.

You probably only want to register one `click` event handler. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="layer1" class="layers">
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer1" />
  <label>layer1</label>
</div>

<div id="layer1" class="layers">
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer2" />
  <label>layer2</label>
</div>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 8);

mymap.on('click', function() {
  $(".layers input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    console.info(this.id, 'is checked');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `legendFunction` adds an event handler to your map (it isn't shown but I'm assuming `map` in `legendFunction` is a jQuery object representing your actual map).  The problem is that it adds a new event handler every time that function runs.  [From the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the same event handler can be bound to an element multiple times.

And all of those duplicated handlers will fire when that event is triggered.  Every time you click a checkbox, your checkbox change handler fires, which in turn calls `legendFunction`, which adds a new click handler to your map.

**Iteration 1**

First time through, `lyrs` is set up as a jQuery object of checked checkboxes, which will be listed on the console.  There is no event handler for clicks on `map` yet (unless `legendFunction()` is fired somewhere else as well, or if you add another click handler somewhere else as well), so `legendFunction` (or rather the event handlers that `legendFunction` adds) does not generate any console output this time.  This iteration adds the first `map` click event handler.

**Iteration 2**

Next time a checkbox is clicked, you'll get the correct `lyrs` logged to the console from your checkbox change handler again.  You haven't described it, but if your checkboxes are actually *on* your `map`, then this same click will bubble up from the checkbox to `map`, and trigger the `map` click handler added in iteration 1 as well.  Depending on your HTML structure, `lyrs` will already be updated with the new set of checked checkboxes, and the output from iteration 1's `map` click handler will reflect that.  Additionally, this click calls `legendFunction()`, and a second, duplicate, `map` click event handler is added.

**Iteration 3**

As above, except now 2 identical `map` click handlers are fired, each generating output on the console.  A third duplicate `map` click event handler is added.

**... etc**

I don't know what exactly the goal is, but to avoid this problem simply create your `map` click event handler once:

```
map.on('click', function() {
    console.log('map was clicked, layers are', lyrs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rebinding the click event multiple times.  Try just outputting the value of lyrs instead of binding the click again in legendFunction.

```
var lyrs;

$("div#myID input:checkbox").change(function() {
lyrs = $("div#myID input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() { return this.id });
console.log('in .change(): ', lyrs)
legendFunction( lyrs );

});

function legendFunction( lyrs ) {
        console.log('in legendFunction: ', lyrs);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`on` method of jquery will add an Event Listener to Event Queue, that is to say, it will add five Event Listeners to Event Queue if you call `on` method for five times.So, it will call Event Callback for five times when `click` Event is triggered, you should cancel all Event Listeners before using `on` method to bind Event Listener.

```js
var lyrs;

$("div#myID input:checkbox").change(function() {
    lyrs = $("div#myID input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() { return this.id });
    console.log('in .change(): ', lyrs)
    legendFunction( lyrs );

});

function legendFunction( lyrs ) {
    map.off('click')
    map.on('click', function() {
        console.log('in legendFunction: ', lyrs);
    });
};
```